# dynamic page title not displaying correctly

Tags: php, dynamic, title

I am trying to dynamically change my page titles. I have the following script inside my header.php page

```
<?php $pagetitle = "Website Home"; ?>
<head>  
<title><?php echo $pagetitle ?></title>  
</head>
```

But instead of my page title displaying as "Website Home", the page title shows up as "`<?php echo $pagetitle ?>`". Is there a reason why the php will not execute inside the `<title>` tags?

Comment: what do you get for `<?php $pagetitle = "Website Home"; ?>`

Comment: Does *any* PHP code execute correctly for you? Anything within `<?php ?>` shouldn't be printed if your interpreter is working.

Comment: If I put `<?php echo $pagetitle ?>` inside the `<body>` tag, then "Website Home" shows up. I am only having the issue inside the `<head><title>` tag. You can see the site at [link](http://www.byukinnect.org/beta/)

Comment: check the source code of the page you are getting !

Comment: May be php code is not working inside html page, in that case Added the 'AddType' handler inside apache conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're calling your header.php some unusual way. Just `include` it in other php script.

Comment: Shrapnel Thanks. I am using a script in my index page that was changing the js script in the header, and this was causing the issue. If I just include the header using `include('header.php');` it works just fine.